# How can I tell why my program requires a specific shared library?

Tags: xcode, linker

I'm working on an OS X application using a third-party framework. This framework is distributed both as shared objects and static objects. For my purposes, I want to use the static objects because I can't rely on the presence of the library on other systems.

However, when I build the application with Xcode, *something* decides it needs the shared objects, and when I run it, dyld tells me off before I even get to my program:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/lib*shared*.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Users/*me*/Library/Developer/Xcode/*snip*/*Application*.app/Contents/MacOS/*Application*
>     Reason: image not found

I ran `otool -L` on the executable, and sure enough, it tried to link against the shared objects (which aren't even installed on my system). However, when I ran it on the thirty-some .a files that I link against, none of them indicated any dependency on them.

Apple's `ld -v` is just a tad verbose: it displays the library search paths but doesn't produce any other kind of useful output.

How can I find what tried to link against the shared objects?

Comment: Can you name the framework?  Or does an agreement prevent naming it?  Does the license allow you to distribute the framework with your application?

Comment: @WaltSellers, the framework in question is radare2, it's licensed under the GPLv3 and I'm happy with the terms. I've also opened an issue on their tracker; I thought that if I asked for radare-specific help here, the answer that I would get would be more about the library than about the tools, so it would be much less useful to someone with a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`otool -L` *does* list the libraries against which any object links.

This specific instance was caused by an Xcode bug (known as rdar://2725744 to the ones blessed with Apple bug database access, and not fixed as of Xcode 6.1.1) where if you try to link against a .a static library with Xcode but there's a .dylib (or .so) dynamic library with the same name in the same directory, the linker will pick the dynamic one.

When you instruct Xcode to link against a static library (say `/some/path/to/my/libFooBar.a`), it adds `-L/some/path/to/my -lFooBar` to the linker invocation. However, with it, `ld` first searches for a dynamic library called `libFooBar.dylib`, and it will fall back to the static library only if it can't find the dynamic one.

Answer (score 0):

If you added the framework is listed in the "Build Phases" of "Link Binary with Libraries" and it has the setting of "Required" that could explain why the launch fails.

Try changing the setting to "Optional".  Then if nothing uses the framework, it should launch fine.  (If something tries to use the framework, but fails to check for it first, it might crash.)

Comment: I only explicitly link to static libraries, and the linker strips, or should strip, any symbol that isn't used. These libraries appear to have dependencies on shared libraries that are not present on my system (even though they successfully built), and these dependencies do not appear in Xcode.

Comment: If that's so, then they must be trying to manually interface to the dynamic linker to get the library loaded.  Otherwise, the link phase in Xcode should not succeed.  I recently added some .a files that referenced an Apple framework which was not listed in Xcode build phases.  My build failed until I added it.

Comment: Okay, so here's what's actually happening. My Xcode solution links against every .a file in the project, but there's a (known) bug in Xcode where if you try to link against a .a archive and there's a .dylib file with the same name in the same folder, it links against the dylib. So that's the issue here.

Comment: I'm not in front of my computer but I know that it's the latest stable one, something like 6.1.1.

Comment: I have Xcode 6.1.1 (6A2008a) and the bug report for this issue is #2725744 (it's not on OpenRadar).